# How to retrieve a <img> into a xml node?

Tags: c#, xml

I work with a rss feed which contains items as below :

```
<item>
    <title>Loi Hamon sur l&#39;e-commerce : ce qu&#39;il faut faire pour &#234;tre pr&#234;t le 13 juin</title>
    <link>http://www.journaldunet.com/ebusiness/commerce/loi-hamon-sur-l-e-commerce.shtml</link>
    <description><![CDATA[<a href="http://www.journaldunet.com/ebusiness/commerce/loi-hamon-sur-l-e-commerce.shtml">
             <img src="http://i-cms.journaldunet.com/image_cms/100/2084358-loi-hamon-sur-l-e-commerce-ce-qu-il-faut-faire-pour-etre-pret-le-13-juin.jpg" align="left" hspace="5" vspace="0"></a>
        Procédures, documents contractuels... Très concrètement, que doivent modifier les e-marchands avant que le volet VAD de la loi consommation n'entre en vigueur ? Réponse.]]>
    </description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 04 Apr 2014 20:14:09 +0200</pubDate>
    <guid>http://www.journaldunet.com/ebusiness/commerce/loi-hamon-sur-l-e-commerce.shtml</guid>
</item>
```

Into the `<description>` Node i want to retrieve the image into `<img>` tag. Is there a way to make that ? I use `System.ServiceModel.Syndication` for the data retrieving. thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I have the following code to retrieve the datas :

```
private IEnumerable<Elements> CreerElements(IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> elements)
{ 
     foreach (SyndicationItem element in elements)
     {
          SyndicationLink lien = element.Links.FirstOrDefault();

          Elements e = new Elements
          {
              Titre = element.Title.Text,
              Url = lien == null ? null : lien.Uri,
              ImageSource = element.Summary.Text.ToString() //<== Here i want to put into the variable the image source. 
          };

          yield return e;
      }
 }
```

And this is the rss feed for sample : http://www.journaldunet.com/web-tech/rss/

Comment: can you provide a feed url?

Comment: Since the img tag is inside a CDATA section, it´s considered plain text and is not present in the document structure seperately. You´ll have to ´character data scan´ the text with the <img> tag. (I would consider a RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is using RegEx to get value of image url as suggested by @MarvinSmit in comment. But if you want to avoid RegEx, there is another way around.

String inside `<description>` element is in html format, so you can pick a library that enable you to handle html comfortably, for example by using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (HAP) from CodePlex :

```
foreach (SyndicationItem element in elements)
{
    SyndicationLink lien = element.Links.FirstOrDefault();

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(element.Summary.Text);
    var url = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img").GetAttributeValue("src", "");

    Elements e = new Elements
    {
        Titre = element.Title.Text,
        Url = lien == null ? null : lien.Uri,
        ImageSource = url;
    };
    yield return e;
}
```

HAP also has a good level of tolerant to malformed html data. It can parse CDATA string in this question to `HtmlDocument` successfully when I tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xPath.

```
XmlDocument doc = New XmlDocument();
doc.Load(XmlAddressHere);
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("\item\description\@img");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with my code it's not applicable. I want to make that with Syndication.

Answer (score 0):

Could be one way to do it

```
        var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://www.journaldunet.com/web-tech/rss/");
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            string description = item.Summary.Text;
            var images = GetImgUrlsFromString(description);
        }
    }

    List<string> GetImgUrlsFromString(string html)
    {
        List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
        var images = html.Split(new string[] { "<img" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (string image in images)
        {
            var srcIndex = image.IndexOf(" src=\"");
            if (srcIndex > -1)
            {
                srcIndex += 6;
                var srcEndIndex = image.IndexOf("\"", srcIndex) + 1;
                string imgSrcUrl = image.Substring(srcIndex, srcEndIndex - srcIndex);
                imageList.Add(imgSrcUrl);
            }
        }
        return imageList;
    }
```